# .NET + C# - Validation not stopping writing to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, textbox

I have made this very very simple registration and login page. But my validations doesnt work. This is .NET and C#.

Can someone please tell me what is going on? And what is going wrong?

http://cego.kimprtf.dk/register

Here is the .NET:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" CssClass="mistake" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You need to say your name!" ControlToValidate="firstName" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" CssClass="mistake" runat="server" ErrorMessage="We need your last name please!" ControlToValidate="lastName" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" CssClass="mistake" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You don't have an Email?" ControlToValidate="emailAdress" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="That's not a real Email!" ControlToValidate="emailAdress" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" CssClass="mistake"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="mistake" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email must match!" ControlToCompare="emailAdress" ControlToValidate="ConfirmEmail"></asp:CompareValidator>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="mistake" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You need a username!" ControlToValidate="Username"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="mistake" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You need a password!" ControlToValidate="Password"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="mistake" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password must match please!" ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"></asp:CompareValidator>

    <asp:TextBox ID="firstName" placeholder="First Name *" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="lastName" placeholder="Last Name *" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="emailAdress" placeholder="Email Adress *" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmEmail" placeholder="Confirm Email Adress *" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Username" placeholder="Username" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" placeholder="Password" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Button ID="SubmitData" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="SubmitData_Click" />
```

And then the C#:

```
protected void SubmitData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            Guid newGUID = Guid.NewGuid();

            /* Connection string til Registerings formen */
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=mssql4.unoeuro.com;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=kimprtf_dk;Password=123kima5");

            /* INSERT COMMAND */
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO kimprtf_dk_db.dbo.Trytry (UserID, firstName, lastName, EmailAdress, Username, Password) VALUES (@ID, @firstName, @lastName, @EmailAdress, @Username, @Password);", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", newGUID.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdress", emailAdress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password.Text);


            /* Åbner connection string'en */
            con.Open();

            /* Execute Non Queries */
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            /* Lukker connection string'en */
            con.Close();

            /* Skriver til client hvis succesfuldt oprettet */
            Response.Write("Your registration is successful!");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }

        /* Clear textboxene som er defineret under (Husk at den skal være i click eventet) */

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            firstName.Text = "";
            lastName.Text = "";
            emailAdress.Text = "";
            ConfirmEmail.Text = "";
            Username.Text = "";
            Password.Text = "";
        }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?
- Kim.

Comment: Well, it looks like you haven't actually included any validation, anywhere.

Comment: Ah i deleted it for some reason... But have requiredfieldvalidations on every textbox have you seen the link?

Comment: I am super uninterested in registering for your site. If you want people to help you with your code you need to post *your code*.

Comment: When I press on my submit button, it just take the empty textboxes and put that into the database. Which is nothing.

Comment: You need to check `Page.IsValid` in your post back.

Comment: Can you write me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't checking that the page has passed validation in your server-side post back event handling code. You should include a check on `Page.IsValid` in your click event handler *before* submitting data to the database, e.g.

```
if(Page.IsValid)
{
    //try/catch block
}
else
{
    //display error text, etc.
}
```

You should *also* be enforcing your user requirements in your database schema as well, so that even if a developer doesn't validate data before submitting to the database, the database itself will reject the record as invalid.